# Returning individual index values of a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, hash

I'm tasked with hashing a vector and returning the hashed index values of each element within the vector. My code is returning the same value for every element however, but I feel like I just need to move something around to fix the problem. What I have so far:

```
void HashNames::hash(string fileName)
{
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    string tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1002; i++)
    {
        infile >> tmp;
        this->nameList.push_back(tmp);
        for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++)
        {
            this->index = djbHash(tmp, 53);
        }
    }
}
int HashNames::djbHash(string data, int table)
{
    int hashVal = 5381;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
    {
        hashVal *= 33;
        hashVal += static_cast<int>(data[i]);
    }
    hashVal %= table;
    return abs(hashVal);
}
void HashNames::printNames()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->nameList.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << this->index << ": " << this->nameList[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

And what the class looks like:

```
class HashNames
{
private:
    int index;
    vector<string> nameList;
    int djbHash(string data, int table);
public:
    void hash(string fileName);
    void printNames();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out myself, I just made another vector of ints and did:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++)
        {
            this->index = djbHash(tmp, 53);
            this->hashTable.push_back(index);
        }
```